# How can I find two symmetric positive definite roots of a symmetric positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, radicals, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix 
$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    9 & 6 \\
    6 & 9 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

I am tasked with finding two different symmetric positive definite matrices B such that $A = B^2$

I found one root using $B = U \Lambda^{1/2} U^{-1}$, with normalized eigenvectors $U =  \begin{bmatrix}
    1/\sqrt(2) & 1/\sqrt(2) \\
    -1/\sqrt(2) & 1/\sqrt(2) \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ and eigenvalues $\Lambda= \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 0 \\
    0 & 15 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$, but I am confused about how to find a 2nd root. Wikipedia states: ***A positive-definite matrix has precisely one positive-definite square root.***

It seems as though I am being asked to find another root that cannot exist. If I were to brute force the equations from $$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    9 & 6 \\
    6 & 9 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$ would I be able to find another positive definite root?

Comment: If you know the eigenvalues of a squared matrix, then the eigenvalues of the original matrix itself are the square roots of the given eigenvalues of the squared matrix. But by square root property, the are two sets of eigenvalues, leading to two solutions. Ofcourse you need lin independent eigenvectors too in the process, they or may not exist and the answer may give you matrices that are not symmetric

Comment: Wikipedia is correct: the task, as stated, is impossible.  Either you're quoting the task wrong, or the source of the task made a mistake.  Perhaps they just meant to ask for two symmetric matrices $B$ such that $A = B^2$?

Comment: After being given A, the verbatim task is: "Show that the matrix A is positive definite and find two different symmetric positive definite matrices B such that $A = B^{2}$."  Taking the negative roots of the eigenvalues would give me $B =     \begin{bmatrix}
    -2.8025 & -1.0705 \\
    -1.0705 & -2.8025 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ which I will check to see if is positive definite, but I am not optimistic

Comment: The negative roots will never produce a positive definite matrix. It's not difficult to show that the (necessarily real, since symmetric) eigenvalues of a positive definite operator are positive, by definition.